# Sharing a Facebook URL (new way)

Tags: share, facebook-opengraph, sharing

The site I work for is currently using the old sharer.php mechanism for sharing a URL.

We have it designed into our site, but want to incorporate a new method of sharing it.

The shares that we have now.. currently have this structure:

http://mysite.com/shorturl
www.mysite.com

Our users are clicking the second URL versus the first URL, and we don't know how to get rid of the www.mysite.com clickable part.

So with the new Facebook like/recommend structure here are my questions:

1) Is it possible to skin the like/recommend how you used to could the Share link?  Use our own custom button to open the share popup or even do it on the page, but just fit it into our style? (Our button is much larger than the Facebook like/recommend button).

2) Is it possible to change, make non-clickable/disabled, or remove the www.mysite.com link from the sharer.php method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No skinning available with the new one thanks to many bone-heads who ruined it for us by abusing that privilege.

2) I cannot figure out what you mean by that. But as a guess, Facebook will count www.example.com as the same as example.com in the counts as long as they end up at the same content with the same og meta tags.  For more information about how the og tags work, see http://ogp.me.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear.  There is two parts to a shown link in the timeline as well as the news feed.

There is the actual URL http://blah.com and then there is the "base URL" that seems to get added below it.. I think this may be site_name?  Just need confirmation.

Comment: I don't know where facebook computes the link from.  I don't see any relevant og tags that you can specify for it.  I think facebook servers look at the base url, lint it, and if it works, then they display that as an extra link.  If they can't lint it, then they don't display that link.